# UI not updating for simple Livewire component

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a small livewire component that searches for users.  The backend appears to work correctly, and if I print out the results from the query, the users returned functions correctly.

In the UI, however, any user that appears in the dropdown will stay, even if the record is no longer present in `$this->users`.

It appears that part of the DOM is not redrawing when the results are returned.  The component is below.

**UserSearch.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Utilities;

use App\Models\Team;
use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class UserSearch extends Component
{
    public $user;
    public $search;
    public $users = [];

    public function mount() {
        $this->user = auth()->user();
    }

    public function selectUser($user) {
        $this->emit('userSelected', $user);
    }

    public function updatedSearch($needle) {
        $this->users = User::teamUsers()->where('name','LIKE',"%$needle%")->get();
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.utilities.user-search',[
            'users' => $this->users
        ]);
    }
}
```

**user-search.blade.php**

```
<div>
    <label for="combobox" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Assigned to</label>
    <div class="relative mt-1">
        <input id="combobox" type="text" class="w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 bg-white py-2 pl-3 pr-12 shadow-sm focus:border-indigo-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:text-sm" role="combobox" aria-controls="options" aria-expanded="false" wire:model="search">
        <button type="button" class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center rounded-r-md px-2 focus:outline-none">
            <!-- Heroicon name: solid/selector -->
            <svg class="h-5 w-5 text-gray-400" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 3a1 1 0 01.707.293l3 3a1 1 0 01-1.414 1.414L10 5.414 7.707 7.707a1 1 0 01-1.414-1.414l3-3A1 1 0 0110 3zm-3.707 9.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 14.586l2.293-2.293a1 1 0 011.414 1.414l-3 3a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-3-3a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
            </svg>
        </button>


        <ul class="absolute z-10 mt-1 max-h-56 w-full overflow-auto rounded-md bg-white py-1 text-base shadow-lg ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none sm:text-sm" id="options" role="listbox">
            <!--
              Combobox option, manage highlight styles based on mouseenter/mouseleave and keyboard navigation.

              Active: "text-white bg-indigo-600", Not Active: "text-gray-900"
            -->
                @foreach($users as $user)
                    <li class="relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-gray-900 cursor-pointer" id="option-0" role="option" tabindex="-1" wire:click="selectUser({{$user}})">
                            <div class="flex">
                                <!-- Selected: "font-semibold" -->
                                <span class="truncate">{{$user->name}}</span>
                                <!-- Active: "text-indigo-200", Not Active: "text-gray-500" -->
                                <span class="ml-2 truncate text-gray-500">{{$user->email}}</span>
                            </div>

                            <!--
                              Checkmark, only display for selected option.

                              Active: "text-white", Not Active: "text-indigo-600"
                            -->
                            <span class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 flex items-center pr-4 text-indigo-600">
                  <!-- Heroicon name: solid/check -->
                          <svg class="h-5 w-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M16.707 5.293a1 1 0 010 1.414l-8 8a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 011.414-1.414L8 12.586l7.293-7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                          </svg>
                        </span>
                    </li>
                @endforeach

            <!-- More items... -->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspected as soon as I posted the question I would find the answer.

This error was caused by conflicting ID's.

I had copied the UI directly from Tailwind and each `<li>` element had the same id, making it impossible for the framework to manage which elements should be removed.

The relevant line now reads:

```
<li class="relative cursor-default select-none py-2 pl-3 pr-9 text-gray-900 cursor-pointer" id="user-{{$user->id}}" role="option" tabindex="-1" wire:click="selectUser({{$user}})">
```